# Does having pagination lessens server load? (theory)

Tags: php, pagination

I was wondering what is the reason behind pagination? is it used because it lessens the burden on the servers since we would technically limit the amount of rows returned per page?

I wanted to do something without pagination but given that i am new to this (i am an amateur) started wondering if its ok technically or not..

Comment: Yes, as @hakre has stated this question is broad and vague. So has been my answer :).

Comment: There are probably UX reasons for doing this as well; you might find it interesting to explore pagination on http://ux.stackexchange.com as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a comment, but it's pretty lengthy, so I post it as an answer:

Your question is pretty broad and it can not be specifically answered. Pagination can save resources, if you only request a subset of data instead of the superset.

So at least in a webapplication/php script pagination saves output data. For example instead of a table that contains 1000 rows with 1000 characters each (roughly 1MB), you would only return 10 rows with 1000 characters (~10kb).

Technically there is no reason that to paginate or not is generally ok or not. It depends on what you'd like to do. So I tend to answer like this in short:

It's technically ok. Go ahead ;) - And next time, please ask a more concrete question, I think that's more helpful for you as well in the end.

Comment: Sure, but a newbie like me has got to ask!

Comment: Sure, it's very okay to ask (and it's clever to think first and then code). If you have more theory type of questions, checkout http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Thanks hakre posted it over there as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, as most of the work is fetching all the data, sorting it and then dividing it into pages. This may be done before the data is requested (indexing), but it's still the hardest work. A server designed to serve data shouldn't care whether it's serving one page, the whole data, or the whole data page by page.

It's mostly for the client, the user and to conserve bandwidth. I'd prefer a phonebook over a mile-long sheet of paper.